# Getting ResponseCompression to work in .NET Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have followed all the documentation to setup ResponseCompression in my .NET Core 2.0 Web API project but I cannot see a difference in the size of the transfer. Here are the before and after results using Postman:

Before Compression:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAuy.jpg

After Compression:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HviP5.jpg

Here is the beginning of my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });
    services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
    });
```

Here is my Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Here is my Get action on my VendorController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var stuff = new Collection<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        stuff.Add($"hello{i}");
    }
    return Ok(stuff);
}
```

I am not using IIS, here is my Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. All the documentation says that this should give me a pretty big difference in the size of my transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression works OK in your case, you just check it not quite right.

Postman shows you the size of non-compressed data actually. It makes sense because Postman is an application that operates with HTTP protocol, and it does not care too much about the size of underlying transfer protocol (like TCP).

The easiest way for you to to see the actual response size is to use Fiddler. You could add `ResponseSize` column that is under `Miscellaneous` collection because it's not actually a part of HTTP response. Then you will see that for such synthetic data the size of compressed packet is indeed more than 10 times smaller that for non-compressed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response CodeFuller, that helped a ton. I'm new to using Postman and Fiddler. So is what I was seeing on Postman the end result because it's already been uncompressed? Is the flow like this:
request (http) --> response (tcp) --> compressed (tcp) --> uncompressed (tcp) --> response (http)? Is there a site or link you can send me to explain in more detail what's going on with TCP/HTTP?

Comment: Compression is a part of HTTP protocol so underlying transport protocol (like TCP) is unaware of it. Postman shows you the size of uncompressed data not because it receives it uncompressed, but because it knows how to calculate the size of original data. Check these articles for a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression and https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/