# General exception from debugger in Visual Studio 2022, debugger process might be corrupted

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging an ASP.NET Web API project. After starting Visual Studio the first time, I try debugging and everything works fine, but after stopping the session and restarting, I get the following error after it hits the breakpoint and I try clicking anything

[image]

This fixes itself by restarting Visual Studio, but then it happens again every time. I want to debug without having to restart Visual Studio.

Do you have any ideas what would cause such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please share more details about your project.

For simply web app project, I am unable to reproduce your issue.

This issue should related to the configuration of your project code.

I there anything like this in your project

[ResponseCompression in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610170/getting-responsecompression-to-work-in-net-core-2-0-web-api#:%7E:text=,cs)

There is a known issue in this situation:

[Hot Reload doen't work with UseResponseCompression Enabled](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38832)

[Compression under HTTPS with dotnet watch and launchBrowser: true breaks some HTML responses](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32767#issuecomment-1020519246)

You can revoke Response configuration or disable hot load.

Comment: thank you for your response, im almost sure this issue has to do with Hot Reload, either way it randomely stopped happening today so im not sure anymore what to make of this...